# How to change the all the nested json values?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the dynamic JSON object like

```
var obj = {
             "name":{
                  "fname" : "David",
                  "lname" : "Seb"
                  },
            "place" : "XXX",
            "country":{
                  "name" : "YYY",
                  "info":{
                          "key":"ZZZ"
                   }
            }
}
```

I want to add some text like "new" in each value.

**Result:**

```
var obj = {
             "name":{
                  "fname" : "Davidnew",
                  "lname" : "Sebnew"
                  },
            "place" : "XXXnew",
            "country":{
                  "name" : "YYYnew",
                  "info":{
                          "key":"ZZZnew"
                   }
            }
}
```

Can anyone please tell how to achieve this one.

Comment: A mix of recursion and loops? Give that a try.

Comment: This isn't JSON, this is Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function traverse(json, ref, k) {
    if(typeof json == "object") {
        $.each(json, function(k, v) {
            traverse(v, json, k);
        });
    } else if(typeof json == "string") {
        ref[k] = json + "new";
    }
}

traverse(obj, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;(function appendNew(obj){
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (typeof obj[i] === 'string') {
            obj[i] += 'new';
        } else if (typeof obj[i] === 'object') {
            obj[i] = appendNew(obj[i]);
        }
    }
    return obj;
})(obj);
```

This function will recursively loop through the object, appending "new" to any strings it finds.

Warning: it will not clone the object, the original object will be modified (i think).